# Rails has_secure_password cannot load such file -- bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, windows-10

I'm trying to create simple authentication in Ruby on Rails.
I'm currently stuck, because after creating table in database and adding in model `has_secure_password` I'm getting error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt`. 
The error occur when I'm trying in `rails console` using basic command: `User.all`.

I have looked at many solutions but nothing helped me.
Currently I have installed bcrypt from `https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git` but still not working.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try restarting the server after installing bcrypt

Comment: You mean just Ctrl + C and one more time run "rails server"? Because i done it many times.

Comment: Yes. Maybe this [link](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142) can help you then?

Comment: I already tried it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but nothing didn't help me. 
Finally I used devise gem instead of doing authentication myself. 
Devise gem also using bcrypt but then code below do the job:

> 1. git clone https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.gi]t
> 2. cd bcrypt-ruby
> 3. gem build bcrypt.gemspec
> 4. gem install gem-compiler
> 5. gem compile bcrypt-3.1.11.gem
> 6. gem install bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32.gem --local

Thank you all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4+, `has_secure_password` is not shipped by default anymore, and you will have to include the `bcrypt` gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt'
```

Run bundler again:

```
> bundle install
```

Then restart your server:

```
> bundle exec rails s
```

More info to be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: Doesn't work. Failed during execution "bundle exec rails s". 
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext

Comment: it seems like it has trouble running its extension. Did you have `gcc` install in your machine? If not, I would suggest install it and re-install the gem.

Comment: Yes, I have gcc installed.

Comment: Then I would still suggest re-install the gem and pay attention to the log to make sure that things are compiled properly.

Comment: Never mind. I used devise gem instead of creating authentication myself. It works fine. Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

On `windows 10` I I solved this using this steps

**Step 1.**

```
gem uninstall bcrypt
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
```

**Step 2**

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

**Step 3**

Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby
```

**devise**

If you use devise then not need add bcrypt gem on your gem file follow below steps

```
gem uninstall bcrypt
 gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Finally, restart your server

Hope to help

Comment: I tried it already. Also not working. Very weird problem. As i wrote before i used devise instead of doing it myself. It works fine.

Comment: If you use devise then try I have updated answer for devise @Rafael

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support but solution which I wrote on new answer have helped me yesterday. :-)