# Ruby on Rails Devise Gem -> LoadError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bcrypt-ruby

Could someone help me.

Using the Devise Gem and just follow the instructions @ https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

See image. When I sign up, I get this error. 
LoadError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skwzq.png)

Comment: this has to do with the ruby/gem version you're using

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246374/4172515